# Firebase Push Notification not receive Message on ios with flutter

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-ios

I have flutter application use firebase messaging, on android platform notification get normaly, but for ios platform i didn't receive any message from firebase, i have followed firebase documentation,
i add APNs Auth key to firebase

[image: APNS on Firebase console]

setup background mode on my runner sign & capabillities

[image: setup on my runner]

and on my AppDelegate.swift i am add

[image: setup on AppDelegate.swift]

result to get token from firebase is success and i send it to my server

[image]

and still i cannot got notification from firebase, even i send directly from firebase admin console, please help if have a same problem, or have advice for fix this problem, thank you.

Comment: check app setting to enable notification request i guess

Comment: I think there is some issue at coding side can you please share your code for handle push notification

Comment: We have to configure from main.dart in flutter

Comment: @ShailandraRajput on main.dart i just initialize the firebase.initializeApp(), and all auth i do on my bloc statement, all is run on android, but on ios i cannot receive the notification